# How to set Right Border of a Column in a Grid?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a Grid like this:

```
<Grid>     
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Row 0, Column 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Row 1, Column 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Row 2, Column 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Row 3, Column 1</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4">Column 1</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

I am not going to actually use TexBlocks in the real application, I used them to make the example easier.
Basically I want to Set the border that devides all the content in Column 0 from Column 1.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the best ways to display a `Border` is to use a `Border` element. You can just declare it *behind* the other content:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" BorderBrush="Black" 
        BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Row 0, Column 1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Row 1, Column 1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Row 2, Column 1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Row 3, Column 1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4">Column 1</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I was trying to use Border, but I thought I had to surround the controls that I wanted to put the border in. I always finding Border in WPF to be a bit confusing. So the border thickness won't take away from the space of my columns no?

Comment: @Dzyann no it won't negate any space concerns because you're just rendering it behind your existing controls via its placement in the tree. Hate to be a stickler, but is exactly what my answer shows just his used a `Border` which is just one of the multiple possible things that could be used to accomplish the same concept.

Comment: @Dzyann, although it won't take space out of the column, if you have a thick `Border` then you *might* need to compensate for it using `Padding` or `Margin` on the other controls.

Comment: Or could just give yourself an additional set width Column to place your border/line effect between the two content Columns to ensure consistent spacing.

Comment: @ChrisW. I feel more comfortable using a Border object to add a Border. It is more clear for the future if someone else has to change my code. I didn't know you could use it like Sheridan did, I thought the syntax was different and that is why I couldn't make it work and had to ask here.

Comment: It may not be obvious right away: what makes the border _be_ a line in between the columns is explicitly specifying zero thickness for all sides but one. I had almost the same code, but with `BorderThickness="1"`, which applies the border to *all* sides, so it took me a bit to figure out why my code was not producing a line...

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of ways to accomplish it, easiest, just draw a line (except I cheated and used a shape...I know, horrible of me right? But you get the idea..) Hope this helps.

```
<Grid>     
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="4" Width="1" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Row 0, Column 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Row 1, Column 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Row 2, Column 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">Row 3, Column 1</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="4">Column 1</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: +1 yeah sorry @ChrisW... my answer is annoyingly similar to yours... I didn't really look before.